# Phase portrait of a non-linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the following system of ODEs, it is in my understanding that to sketch trajectories in the $SI$-plane, one has to first find the critical point(s), which is only the point $(0, 0)$ in this case, then linearize the system, that is derive its Jacobian matrix at $(0, 0)$, and then find the eigenvalues of the new system. However, the result is that the eigenvalues are $\lambda = -\beta$ and $\lambda = 0$, so the trajectories appear to be just straight vertical lines, which seems dubious to me.

$S'=-\alpha S I,\\
I'=\alpha S I - \beta I,\\
R'=\beta I$

$S(0)=S_0,\\
I(0)=I_0,\\
R(0)=R_0$

In this system, $S(t), I(t)$, and $R(t)$ represent various kinds of populations, and $\alpha, \beta >0$ are constants.

I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: No, you do not need to find stationary points here (which are actually fill all axis with $I=0$). The most straightforward way to sketch the phase portrait is to divide the second equation by the first, integrate and find a first integral. Using almost obvious fact that $I\to 0$ will give you the direction along the orbits.

Comment: @Artem As far as I see, we also have another first integral $R+I+S = {\rm const}$. I don't know whether it is in involution with your integral, but two integrals could be great for this problem.

Comment: @Evgeny These first integrals are different, actually $R$ acts as an extraneous variable here and one can forget it. The one Artem is alluding to is $S^βe^{α(I−S)}$, involving only $(S,I)$.

Comment: @Did They are different, but it's better then they are involutive. In that case integral curves lie exactly at intersections of level surfaces of two different first integrals. Of course the formula that we get in the end would be the same for both methods and sketch would be absolutely the same too.

Comment: @Artem: do you mean that $I$ approaches $0$ as $t\to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, you will need directions along your orbits, you can figure them out by noticing that $S'<0$ or $I\to 0$ for $t\to\infty$.

Comment: @Artem: if we divide the second equation by the first, we get

$\frac{dI}{dS}=\frac{\beta-\alpha S}{\alpha S} \implies I(S)= \frac{\beta}{2}\ln|S|-S+C$. Do you think this is the correct equation for trajectories in the $SI$-plane?

Also, how do you see that $I\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. Is it necessary to solve for $I(t)$ in order to see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

The lines $S=0$ and $I=0$ are invariant. The second is composed of fixed points and on the first you have $I'=-\beta I$ showing that all goes to the origin. Finally, the line $S=\beta/\alpha$ determines almost all that is missing, since $I'=(\alpha S-\beta)I$.
You can sketch the phase portrait considering the signs of $S'$ and $I'$ in the six regions determined by the 3 lines.

Notice that all but one of the invariant curves has the line $S=0$ as an asymptote (I write on purpose "invariant curves", not "trajectories").

Comment: Is $I(S)=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\ln|S| - S + \text{constant}$ a valid function for the curves?

Comment: Indeed it is an integral.